# Will fseek function flush data in the buffer in C++?

Tags: c++, file, fseek

We know that calls to functions like fprintf or fwrite will not write data to the disk immediately; instead, the data will be buffered until a threshold is reached. My question is: **if I call the fseek function, will these buffered data be written to disk before seeking to the new position? Or is the data still in the buffer, and is written to the new position?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware if the buffer is guaranteed to be flushed, it may not if you seek to a position close enough. However there is no way that the buffered data will be written to the new position. The buffering is just an optimization, and as such it has to be transparent.

Comment: So you mean this kind of calls is all right: (1)fwrite...(2)fseek...(3)fwrite... and all the data will in the right position?

Comment: Yes, you can be certain that `fseek` will work just as if there was no buffering at all.

Comment: Can you cite text in the C standard to support this view?  (I believe it is incorrect, but I don't have my copy of the C standard here to verify.)  And buffering is certainly not "just an optimization"; many aspects of buffering are covered by the standard (e.g. `fflush`, `setbuf`, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes; `fseek()` ensures that the file will look like it should according to the `fwrite()` operations you've performed.

The C standard, ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §7.19.9.2 `fseek()` (C11 [§7.21.9.2 The `fseek` function](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2), says:

> The fseek function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream.
> If a read or write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and fseek fails.

Comment: Given the text of your answer and the section that you have quoted, are you saying that the `fseek` must be doing the equivalent of a `fflush`? It wasn't quite clear to me.

Comment: @CBBailey — the standard doesn't say that a flush happens, just that the file position will be changed.  But the file must be correct.  If you seek from an offset of 1 KiB to an offset of 1 MiB and there is data to be written, it will be written.  OTOH, if you seek from offset 1024 to 1056, there may be no need to write the data to disk — the buffer may still contain the information and not need to be written.  Check the standard that I've linked to — that's what matters.  POSIX [`fseek()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html)
has extra information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it's specified that the data must be flushed on a `fseek` but when the data is actually written to disk it must be written at that position that the stream was at when the write function was called. Even if the data is still buffered, that buffer can't be written to a different part of the file when it is flushed even if there has been a subsequent seek.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your real concern is whether previously-written (but not yet flushed) data would end up in the wrong place in the file if you do an `fseek`.

No, that won't happen. It'll behave as you'd expect.

Answer (score -1):

I have vague memories of a requirement that you call `fflush` before
`fseek`, but I don't have my copy of the C standard available to verify.
(If you don't it would be undefined behavior or implementation defined,
or something like that.) The common Unix standard specifies that:

> If the most recent operation, other than ftell(), on a given stream is
>   fflush(), the file offset in the underlying open file description
>   shall be adjusted to reflect the location specified by fseek().
>
> [...]
>
> If the stream is writable and buffered data had not been written to
>   the underlying file, fseek() shall cause the unwritten data to be
>   written to the file and shall mark the st_ctime and st_mtime fields of
>   the file for update.

This is marked as an extention to the ISO C standard, however, so you can't count on it except on Unix platforms (or other platforms which make similar guarantees).

Comment: consider for example 7.19.5.3/6: "output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a ﬁle positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind)". This is not definitive, but if it were required to call `fflush` after output and before `fseek`, then this mention of `fseek` would be redundant since there would be a flush anyway.

Comment: @Steve That may be the restriction I was thinking of---as I said, I **vaguely** remember a requirement to call `fflush`, but I don't have my copy of the standard handy to verify where it was (and since I normally only use C++ I/O, I don't actively remember C style IO).