# Skip in standard input/output stream

Tags: c, file-io

Why operations connected with changing pointer position in file needs to do one of those:

- read value (i.e. `fread()`)
- flush stream (i.e. `fseek()`)

For example: I know that next 10 bytes are unnecessary offset and I can simply skip them, so why I need to reset position indicator or read those 10 bytes and ignore them. I would want just move pointer those 10 bytes forward without any side effects. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: flush isn't done using `fseek` but `fflush`

Comment: to skip bytes from standard input, you need to read them & discard them. Seeking doesn't work, input streams (and output streams) aren't seekable.

Comment: But isn't that fseek needs to flush its cache before changing position?

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted something, I meant this one http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand clearly, but after reading that you wrote I assume that file is something like special case of stream that allows to do `fseek`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `fseek()` does imply an `fflush()`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495891/will-fseek-function-flush-data-in-the-buffer-in-c

Comment: I must have misintepreted the first version of the question. I thought it was about stdin/stdout.

Comment: Could you please reopen this question?

Comment: I have changed the duplicate target. This is still a duplicate. If I'm proven wrong, I'll reopen, no issue.